# C++ Sum parameter pack into a template argument

Tags: c++, c++20, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

How can I sum all the `std::size_t` parameters passed through the template into one `std::size_t` value that will define the size of the array.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t... N>
class Example {
    std::array<T, N + ...> data; // std::array<T, sum of all N...>
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it.  You need to use a fold expression for this which is the same syntax, just surrounded with `()`.  That gives you

```
template<typename T, std::size_t... N>
struct Example {
    std::array<T, (N + ...)> data; // std::array<T, sum of all N...>
};
```

And in this example you'll get an error that tells you the array member has the size of the sum of the parameters.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t... N>
struct Example {
    std::array<T, (N + ...)> data; // std::array<T, sum of all N...>
};

template <typename T>
struct get_type;

int main() 
{
    Example<int, 1, 2, 3> ex;
    get_type<decltype(ex.data)>{};
}
```

Error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:27:33: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct get_type<std::array<int, 6> >'
   27 |     get_type<decltype(ex.data)>{};
      |                                 ^
main.cpp:22:8: note: declaration of 'struct get_type<std::array<int, 6> >'
   22 | struct get_type;                                             ^
      |        ^~~~~~~~                                              |
                              // here you see 1 + 2 + 3 == 6 --------+
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31e96d09955fc973)

Comment: I actually don't get the error you were talking about, the parentheses just fixes it. Im on C++20 gcc version 11.1.0

Comment: @CedricMartens It's the extra `get_type` code which intentionally creates the error, to check that it got the expected answer.

Comment: @CedricMartens Like aschepler said, you'll only get the error when when you sun my demo code.  I do that just to have the compiler confirm the type is as expected.

Comment: Makes sense! I just `std::cout << ex.data.size() << std::endl;` :)

Comment: @CedricMartens Or you could just do that :)